# Riemann integral counterexample to dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, pointwise-convergence

The dominated convergence theorem (and similar theorems) is often [claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to be what makes Lebesgue integration superior to Riemann integration. But we also have the result that any (positive) Riemann-integrable function is Lebesgue integrable and that both integrals agree in this case. Thus it seems naively reasonable that the dominated convergence theorem should apply to Riemann integrals too.

Let $f_n:I\to\mathbb R^+$, where $I$ is any interval in $\mathbb R$ (possibly infinite), be a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions that converge pointwise to $f$. Suppose further that $|f(x)|\leqslant |g(x)|$ on $I$ for some Riemann-integrable function $g(x)$.

1. Do we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{I,\text{Riemann}}f_n(x)dx=\int_{I,\text{Riemann}}f(x)dx$ ?
2. What if we add the premise that $f$ is also Riemann integrable?

If the answer to (1) turns out to be "no," what's a counterexample?

Comment: Looks OK.  Lebesgue integrals cover a wider class.  It is possible that f may be Lebesgue integrable, but not Riemann.

Answer (score 5):

For example, let $r_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, and let $f_n$ be the indicator function of $\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\}$.  Then $f_n$ are Riemann integrable with $|f_n| \le 1$, 
but $f_n$ converges pointwise to the indicator function of the rationals, which is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Nice. And as per my part 2, this example is ruled out if we insist that $f$ be Riemann integrable. Does that added premise make dominated converge hold?

Answer (score 1):

The first part has been seen to be **false**.

For the second part, it seems to be **false**, too. Let $I=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)=n\, \mathbb I([0,\frac1n])$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f=0$ which is integrable. However $\lim\int f_n=1$ while $\int f=0$. I think the proper assumption should be $f_n\leqslant g$ instead of $f\leqslant g$. Then we can apply dominated convergence theorem and conclude by the fact that Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral conincide. (In fact the proof would be tough if you don't use any Lebesgue theory.)

Comment: You're right, the question I really intended is whether $(2)$ holds when $f_n \leqslant g$. Also, I think your intervals should be $(0, \frac1n]$, since otherwise $f_n(0)$ diverges.